# Cocos2d-x how to correctly use MoveTo action for dragging sprite

Tags: drag-and-drop, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using the code bellow to drag a sprite on a vertical axis. But using MoveTo action for the sprite to follow the touch just makes it go crazy, although just set position to touch location works fine.

```
//// Move Player
// Location
touchMovedLocation = ( touch -> getLocationInView() );
touchMovedLocation = ( this -> convertToNodeSpace(touchMovedLocation) );
// Translation
touchMovedLocation = Vec2(( lift -> getPosition().x ), touchMovedLocation.y);
touchMovedLocation = ( this -> boundLiftMovement(touchMovedLocation) );
// Move
auto action = MoveTo::create(0.2f, touchMovedLocation);
( lift -> runAction(action) );
//( lift -> setPosition(touchMovedLocation) );
```

Comment: actions are inappropriate for dragging, just set the position directly

Comment: Got it. But then is there a way to limit the speed of the sprite while dragging it?

Comment: then whip out trigonometry and move the sprite towards or onto the target position depending on its distance to target and given speed. Tip: (target-current) >> normalize result, multiply by speed, add result to current sprite pos

Comment: check my answer in here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701720/how-to-perform-drag-and-drop-operation-on-sprite-fetched-from-array-and-present